# Azure B2C custom policies can't integrate with API Management

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-api-management

I tried to config Azure B2C using **custom policies** and API Management Identities but it was not success.

1. When i used Azure B2C built-in policies, it worked perfectly.
2. When i used Azure B2C custom policies (with [xml files](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/tree/master/SocialAndLocalAccounts)), the Azure B2C provider appeared on APIM login page. After login success, i got an error message "Authentication has failed."

Does Azure B2C custom polices support APIM identities?

Thank you for you help!

Comment: I have done. It can support APIM identities

Comment: Could you post the details of how you got it working?